# Passing parameters for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Test]
    (@ID INT,
     @month VARCHAR(10),
     @Low INT,
     @standard FLOAT = 0)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table1] 
               WHERE ID = @ID AND month = @month 
                 AND TYPE = 'S' AND TYPEID = @Low)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Table1] 
        SET Add = @standard
        WHERE ID = @ID AND month = @month 
          AND TYPE = 'S' AND TYPEID = @Low
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Table1] (ID, month, Add, TYPE, TYPEID) 
        VALUES (@ID, @month, @standard, 'S', @Low)
    END
GO
```

This is the table which is missing March dates

```
ID     Month    Add    Type    TypeID
---------------------------------------
333    feb      4       S        111
333    April    4       S        111
```

So I thought by refreshing the stored procedure this would fill in for the month of March.

But when I execute the procedure using

```
Use [DB1]
GO

DECLARE @RV int
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @month varchar(10)
DECLARE @Low int
DECLARE @Add int
DECLARE @standard float

EXECUTE @RV = [Test] 
              @ID int,
              @month varchar(10),
              @Low int,
              @Add int,
              @standard float
GO
```

I get

```
  ID        Month      Add        Type     TypeID
  -----------------------------------------------
  333       feb         4           S        111
  333       April       4           S        111
  NULL      NULL        NULL        S        NULL
```

Although I am looking for

```
  ID        Month      Add        Type      TypeID
  ------------------------------------------------
  333       feb         4           S        111
  333       April       4           S        111
  333       Mar         4           S        111
```

I am assuming I am not passing the parameters correctly or something. Can anyone advise on this? Thanks

Comment: Why not just put a select of your parameters into the procedure and see what you are passing?

Comment: The syntax you have to call your procedure is invalid. What code are you actually using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring your parameters to pass into the stored procedure but you're not assigning them a value anywhere, so the procedure has nothing to work with.

You need to change the execution statement to something like this:

```
Use [DB1]
GO
DECLARE @RV int = 0;
DECLARE @ID int = 333;
DECLARE @month varchar(10) = 'Mar';
DECLARE @Low int = 111;
DECLARE @Add int = 4;
DECLARE @standard float = 4;

EXECUTE @RV = [Test] 
@ID = @ID,
@month = @month,
@Low = @Low,
@Add = @Add,
@standard = @standard;
GO
```

Replace the 0's and 1.0 with whatever values want to use.

<del>Also, `month` is a string column in your table but you're passing in an `INT` to the procedure.  You need to change the `@month` parameter to match the datatype of your table column.</del>
(removed after your edit)

Comment: How would you run this dynamically? Not having to specify the ID etc

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL or a cursor

Comment: `Also, month is a string column in your table but you're passing in an INT to the procedure. You need to change the @month parameter to match the datatype of your table column.` <<< Very true. Granted SQL will coerce an `int` into `varchar`. So that won't cause a failure, beyond making my eye twitch. I extremely dislike implicit type conversion. :-)